# How to add the nodes of a tree in a list?

Tags: tree, ocaml

I want to add the nodes of a tree to a list in preorder without concatenating lists.

```
type 'a bintree = Nil | BT of 'a bintree * 'a * 'a bintree
let preorder t = 
  let rec addpre t list = 
    match t with
    | Nil -> list
    | BT (left, v, right) -> addpre left (v :: list)
  in 
  addpre t [];;

let ab = BT (BT(Nil, 2, Nil),
             7,
             BT(BT(Nil, 5, Nil), 6, BT(Nil, 11, Nil)))
let r = preorder ab;;
```

As you can see I know how to add the nodes from a branch (left or right) but I do not know how to add the nodes from both branches. Can you help me out?

**UPDATE**

I think I managed to do it

```
let preorder t = 
  let rec addpre t list = 
    match t with
    | Nil -> list
    | BT (left, v, right) -> v :: addpre left (addpre right list)
  in 
  addpre t [];;
```

Is it right?

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to compute `countpree` over `right`  after having computed it over `left`. 
A local binding of the computation over the left part could help.
Something like

```
| BT (left, v, right) -> 
      let leftpreoder = countpre left (v :: list) 
      in ...
```

Comment: I get an error: "Error: This expression has type 'a list
but an expression was expected of type 'a
The type variable 'a occurs inside 'a list".

Comment: without your code, I can't help you much. My guess is that you are trying to insert the resulting list into a list using `::`.

Answer (score 0):

Using an accumulator and stack of nodes waiting to be processed, we can achieve this with tail-recursion.

```
let preorder t =
  let rec aux t acc stack =
    match t, stack with
    | Nil, [] -> acc
    | Nil, x::xs -> aux x acc xs
    | BT (l, v, r), _ -> aux l (v::acc) (r::stack)
  in
  aux t [] [] 
  |> List.rev
```

Breaking down a sample call using the data you've shown.

```
preorder (BT (BT(Nil, 2, Nil), 7, BT(BT(Nil, 5, Nil), 6, BT(Nil, 11, Nil))))
aux (BT (BT(Nil, 2, Nil), 7, BT(BT(Nil, 5, Nil), 6, BT(Nil, 11, Nil)))) [] []
aux (BT(Nil, 2, Nil)) [7] [BT(BT(Nil, 5, Nil), 6, BT(Nil, 11, Nil))]
aux Nil [2; 7] [Nil; BT(BT(Nil, 5, Nil), 6, BT(Nil, 11, Nil))]
aux Nil [2; 7] [BT(BT(Nil, 5, Nil), 6, BT(Nil, 11, Nil))]
aux (BT(BT(Nil, 5, Nil), 6, BT(Nil, 11, Nil))) [2; 7] []
aux (BT(Nil, 5, Nil)) [6; 2; 7] [BT(Nil, 11, Nil)]
aux Nil [5; 6; 2; 7] [Nil; BT(Nil, 11, Nil)]
aux Nil [5; 6; 2; 7] [BT(Nil, 11, Nil)]
aux (BT(Nil, 11, Nil)) [5; 6; 2; 7] []
aux Nil [11; 5; 6; 2; 7] [Nil]
aux Nil [11; 5; 6; 2; 7] []
List.rev [11; 5; 6; 2; 7]
[7; 2; 6; 5; 11]
```

Or a straightforward conversion of this to create a sequence. This saves us the trouble of building up an accumulator, and then reversing it.

```
let preorder_seq t =
  let rec aux t stack () =
    match t, stack with
    | Nil, [] -> Seq.Nil
    | Nil, x::xs -> aux x xs ()
    | BT (l, v, r), _ -> Seq.Cons (v, aux l (r::stack))
  in
  aux t []
```

Testing:

```
# BT (BT(Nil, 2, Nil), 7, BT(BT(Nil, 5, Nil), 6, BT(Nil, 11, Nil))) 
  |> preorder_seq
  |> List.of_seq;;
- : int list = [7; 2; 6; 5; 11]
```